# Changes or improvements in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.2, version

Magento will introduce Magento version 2.2.2. So what will be changes and improvements in Magento 2.2.2?

I tried to search on google for version Magento 2.2.2 but didn't find anything about magento2.2.2.

Comment: This one will help for you http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html

Answer (score 3):

Magento will release Magento version **2.2.2** and also **2.1.11** approx. **12/13 dec**

**Here list of New Features, Fixes and enhancements, Functional fixes etc.**

> **New Features:**

• Streamlined **Instant Purchase checkout**. Our new streamlined Instant Purchase option uses
previously-stored payment credentials and shipping information to bypass steps in the
checkout process.

• Integrated **dotmailer marketing automation software**. Magento is one of the first
ecommerce solutions to include the dotmailer marketing automation with their core product.

• **Advanced Reporting** powered by Magento Business Intelligence. Access easy-to-use
order, product, and customer reports right from the Magento Admin to gain new insights and
enable data-driven decision making.

• **Magento Shipping**. This new feature provides integrated advanced multi-carrier shipping and
fulfillment.

> **Fixes and enhancements**

• **Significant enhancements for payment methods**. We've added support for the Indian
**Rupee (INR) to PayPal Express Checkout** as well as a fix for an issue where some Braintree
refunds did not work.

• **Improvements to multi-storeview sites**. Switching store views multiple times no longer
results in an error on the storefront.

• **New functionality for the command-line interface**. We've added interactivity to the
admin:user:create command and added ability to handle CLI setup interactively (with
prompts).

• You can now the Enter key (in addition to a mouse click) to search tables in the Admin.

• Magento **no longer creates duplicate shipments** when merchants create shipments with
bundled products via API.

> **Functional fixes**

**Catalog**

• You can now enter **strings that exceed 255 characters** in Admin or frontend input fields.
Previously, Magento saved only the first 255 characters of a long input string.

• Magento now renders color attribute **swatches correctly for the search result** page if sorting for color attribute is enabled.

• The **`\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection` now returns
items** that have only existing relations in catalog_product_entity table. It no longer loads
quote items with non-existing products.

• Magento **no longer duplicates attribute option values**. Previously, Magento did not confirm the uniqueness of an attribute option value if you created it using REST

**Cart and checkout**

• You can now view the Products in **cart report if the cart contains a bundle or a grouped
product**. Previously, when you viewed the Products in cart report, Magento threw an exception
under these conditions.

• Magento now recognizes zip codes without spaces for addresses located in the Netherlands.

• Addresses with a value of 0 in saveInAddressBook are no longer added to the address
book for new customers. Previously, if you placed an order as a guest and set the
save_in_address_book for an address on 0, that address was still copied to the customer
address book when registering as a new customer on the checkout success page.

• Magento now a**ccepts coupon codes with special characters** during checkout.

• We've **improved cache control headers.**

**You can read full doc here: [Magento 2.2.2 Release Doc](https://info2.magento.com/rs/585-GGD-959/images/Draft%20Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%202.2.2%20and%202.1.11.pdf?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTjJKak0yUmhORGhpTjJZNSIsInQiOiJxcm5cLzNDczQzZEhRc1V3UVg1QVZLMFBCWEhWRlVQcDM3RHJ0OGpLcnBMQUZqMGlcL3VlejJSVjlTSFIwNlJKYkxsc3FBY2tBUWxzOEYzZTZkNFNMKzNaZnhTN2UzUmMwTEZCQ2JmdnRkNDRFMlpZakZyZlBZZytPMytaWW5MUk0yIn0%3D)**

**Read Release Notes [http://devdocs.magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.2CE.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the doc :) but how you found the doc? @Prince

Comment: @KeyurShah I got mail from Magento partner portal.